# Can't build flutter application for ios?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mapbox-gl, flutter-getx

I'm using mapbox_gl for my project, when I build the app for ios iPad pro (9.7-inch) I got this error:-

`Building for iOS Simulator, but linking in dylib built for iOS, file '...project_name/ios/Pods/Mapbox-iOS-SDK/dynamic/Mapbox.framework/Mapbox' for architecture arm64`

Answer (score 3):

According to this issue - https://github.com/flutter-mapbox-gl/maps/issues/890

just add the following to your podfile

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '9.0'
        config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64 i386 armv7"

    end
  end
end
```

replacing

```
 post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

*as mentioned by @samia also .*
***This all worked for me too***

- Now, For platform issue just uncomment `# platform :ios, '9.0'` , in your podfile and set it to '10.0' instead of '9.0'
  (although I didn't need this for mapbox)
- For second warning , I ignored it and app works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

this looks similar to https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native-ios/issues/487

adding this to the podfile fixed this for me in flutter on an m1 mac

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
    config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
  end
end
```

Comment: I did the same, but now I got this warning

[!] Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `9.0` on target `Runner` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.

[!] CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because your project already has a custom config set. In order for CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base configurations of the target `Runner` to ......

Comment: `Runner` to `Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.profile.xcconfig` or include the `Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.profile.xcconfig` in your build configuration (`Flutter/Release.xcconfig`).